# my first extension - add bookmark with a click - HOW TO?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am learning to write javascript and Chrome extensions. I want an extension that will show a button, and when a user clicks the button it will add a bookmark folder in the bookmarks.
 So far so good (the button appears), but clicking it adds nothing.

I suppose my JavaScript is not correct.

Here is the code:

Manifest:

```
{
  "name": "My First Extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "background_page": "background.html",
  "permissions": [
    "tabs", "http://*/*", "bookmarks"
  ],
  "browser_action": {
      "default_icon": "icon.png",
      "name": "HELLO WORLD"
  }
}
```

background.html:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>

  function updateIcon() {
    chrome.bookmarks.create({parentId: bookmarkBar.id,
                         title: 'Extension bookmarks'});
                  }

  chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(updateIcon);
  updateIcon();

);
</script>
</head>
</html>
```

I suppose it is this part:

```
function updateIcon() {    chrome.bookmarks.create({parentId: bookmarkBar.id,
                     title: 'Extension bookmarks'});
              }
```

That code is wrong.

Please, advise me and any good places for learning JavaScript. I have read [this web page](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/bookmarks.html) already.

Comment: have you read : http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/getstarted.html ?

Comment: Try the Mozilla JavaScript Guide: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an obvious syntax error.

```
  function updateIcon() {
    chrome.bookmarks.create({parentId: bookmarkBar.id,
                         title: 'Extension bookmarks'});
                  }

  chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(updateIcon);
  updateIcon();

); // <-- what is this doing here?
```